# Prove that for any convex function $f(x)+f(y)\le f(x-1)+f(y+1)$ for all $x<y$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

As per the definition of convex function 
$f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\le \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2) \forall\lambda\in[0,1]\\ \forall x_1,x_2\in\Bbb{R}$
There is a hint for this problem- try to replace $\lambda, x_1,x_2$ with something involving $x,y$ to get that desired inequality. Remember $x<y$
I have also tried using slop condition of convex function, but can't prove it. 
Can anyone solve this? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: I think the inequality should be $f(x) - f(y) \leq f(x-1) - f(y-1)$, otherwise there exists a counterexample.

Comment: It is still false.

Comment: I suspect the inequality is $f(x)+f(y) \le f(x-1) + f(y\color{red}{+}1)$ for $x < y$. If that is the case, it is a special case of [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata's_inequality) and above wiki entry has a proof of that.

Comment: @ZhaohuiDu Could you check my answer?

Comment: @SeewooLee you modification is also true, it is also a special case of karamata inequality.

Comment: @achillehui yes I just saw this, thanks!

Comment: Yes I have made mistake while typing, I have rectified it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  false for $f(x)=x^{2}$.

Hint for the revised question:

$x=\alpha (x-1)+(1-\alpha) (y+1)$ where $\alpha =\frac {y+1-x} {y+2-x}$. Apply the definition of convexity. Similarly we can write $y$ in the form $\beta (x-1)+(1-\beta) (y+1)$. Apply the definition again and add the two inequalities.

Comment: There was a mistake in my question, I have fixed it now.

Comment: @BiswarupSaha I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Got it. Nice idea, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'll give a sketch of proof for a modified problem: $f(x) - f(y) \leq f(x-1) - f(y-1)$. This is equivalent to $f(x) - f(x-1) \leq f(y) - f(y-1)$.

Convexity of $f$ is equivalent to the following: for $x_{1} < x_{2} < x_{3}$, $$s(x_{1}, x_{2}) \leq s(x_{1}, x_{3}) \leq s(x_{2}, x_{3})$$
where 
$$
s(x, y) = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x}
$$
is a slope of the secant line. Using this, we have
$$
f(x) - f(x-1) = s(x-1, x) \leq s(x-1, y) \leq s(y-1, y) = f(y) - f(y-1). 
$$
Equivalence can be proved by replacing $\lambda, x_{1}, x_{2}$ with appropriate variables, which may be in somewhere on Google. (I can't find it now, but I'm sure that it is true.)